# Openlayer interaction: callbacks not getting fired

Tags: angular, openlayers, openstreetmap, openlayers-6

I'm trying to listen for PinchZoom interaction but I'm getting nothing in the callback.

**Creating the map**

```
this.map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM(),
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2,
      }),
    });
```

**Listening for pinch interactions**

```
const mapInteraction = new PinchZoom();
mapInteraction.on('change:active', (event) => {
      console.log('event', event);
    });
this.map.addInteraction(mapInteraction);
```

I've tried with MouseWheelZoom event also, but the same issue occurs there too. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of these "on" functions?

Here's a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular10-openlayers-demo-41up43)

Comment: The `change:active` event corresponds to the `setActive` function which enables or disables the interaction. It does not inform you about any current user interactions.